# rendering an aspx page in another one

Tags: c#, asp.net, rendering

In my web project's business object editor page, I'm sending a notification email to the administrator after an object insert or update. But instead of sending a plain text mail, i want to send the html output of another aspx page(Notification.aspx) i simply prepared for this purpose.

First i thought, I can create an instance of Notification.aspx then use it's RenderControl method for getting the output.

However, in the codebehind of Editor.aspx page, i can't even reach the Notification's reference to create a new instance.

I wonder what is the best practice for loading and rendering a page in another one...

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can render a page by doing this:

```
StringWriter _writer = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("MyPage.aspx", _writer);

string html = _writer.ToString();
```

Comment: I never knew about that overload. Turns out there's another one that takes a IHttpHandler - which would allow you to subscribe to Page events and modify the output before rendering. Very nice, and significantly simplifies my EmailPageHandler code below. +1

Comment: thanks. that made the trick in simplest way :)

now i also wonder can i make this process asynchronously? because it takes some time to generate the mail body's html

Comment: I would do that by creating a new Thread, put the render code in a method. And execute the method in the new Thread.

Answer (score 0):

See this question/answer: [Can I set up HTML/Email Templates in C# on ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620265/can-i-set-up-html-email-templates-in-c-on-asp-net/620337#620337). Mark Brackett has what you're looking for, though there's a lot of other helpful advice there as well.

Answer (score 0):

The page class is instantiated by the ASP.NET runtime when a request is made. So you can make a request and get the capture the response:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://mysite.com/notification.aspx"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds tricky. Keep in mind the page will need an appropriate HttpContext as well, in order to render correctly.

I would consider using a UserControl instead. These can be simply loaded and rendered with the `Page.LoadControl()` method. With a bit of jiggery-pokery, you can keep it from rendering in the page while extracting it's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

RenderControl won't work, because the Page won't go through it's lifecycle. I've used an HttpHandler and a Response.Filter to capture the stream in the past for a similar purpose.  I've posted code over at the [ASP.NET forums previously](http://forums.asp.net/p/1200166/2088266.aspx#2088266).

Edit: If you need to modify page output, you should combine this with the [Server.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150027.aspx) overload [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647833/rendering-an-aspx-page-in-another-one/647866#647866) by MartinNH. That would simplify the code, removing the Response.Filter and such. If you just want the page output directly, MartinNH's method is *very* clean.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you looking for:

```
Type t = BuildManager.GetCompiledType("~/mypage.aspx");
Page p = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
p.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
```

from here use your imagination....