# String Manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, string-formatting

I am working on c# .net application, and using crystal reports. I need to print crystal reports on dot matrix printer, but speed of printing is very slow as crystal reports prints in graphical mode. So i moves to dos based printing and use RawPrinter helper class to print it. That works completly fine.

But writing a dataset to a text file(in invoice report format), uses lots of string manipulation for positioning the characters, spacing etc. I use string builder class and padding and lots of if, else to print page totals, grand totals, taxes etc.

Writing a text file in this way is such a pain.

Please suggest me some other feasible and effective approach.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear *what* exactly is a pain. If you could post a sample of code so we can try to refactor it, that would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Perhaps get your organisation to stop messing around using dot matrix printers and upgrade!

Comment: Surely buying a new printer is cheaper than all that development time?

Comment: I assume you know you can now do "multi part printing" on a laser printer, see http://www.royalegraphics.co.uk/html/ncr-laser-paper.html for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the dataset to XML ([`DataSet.WriteXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx)) and transform it to another textual format using [XSLT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313997).

Comment: Will you please give me some code for it, just few lines. Any helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of [templateing engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor), but as you are not doing HTML you need the engine to be stand-alone.   See [C# template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518954/c-template-engine) for some options.

XSLT is a good option if you like XML and already know how to use it, otherwise I would tend to code with a more "code focused" solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and changing printers was not a solution because of 1800 or so clients using dot matrix printers. So solution I came up with was to use a templating engine (StringTemplate http://www.stringtemplate.org/), get the output text file and send it to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

use tabs for everything.  it will let you put stuff in tab columns automatically.