# Replace string with property which is extract from list

Tags: c#

I have an issue here.

I'm getting string which may looks like : "simple text : {1}, and date : {3}" -> getting this from database
I want to replace "{1}" with employee.Name and "{3}" with Date.Now. 
Which number replace with what I know from the database, there are a lot of different types so I need to do that dynamically, so String replace should look like :

```
String.Replace("{someNumber}", extract from the database but it is a string but should be property like emplayee.Name).
```

I have no idea how to do that because function put "emplayee.Name" instead of "John", which is employeeName.

Here is a sample : 
`content = content.Replace(match.ToString(), emailVariableDictionary[ExtractIdFromMatch(match.ToString())].Variable);`

emailVariableDictionary is a List which contains strings like "employee.Name, Date.Now" and like a said before String.Format put "emplyee.Name" instead of "John"

Comment: maybe You want "template engine" ?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518954/c-sharp-template-engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use String Interpolation Concept. Its available in below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

**Example:**

```
string name = "Mark";
var date = DateTime.Now;

// Composite formatting:
Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}! Today is {1}, it's {2:HH:mm} now.", name, date.DayOfWeek, date);
// String interpolation:
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}! Today is {date.DayOfWeek}, it's {date:HH:mm} now.");
// Both calls produce the same output that is similar to:
// Hello, Mark! Today is Wednesday, it's 19:40 now.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var template = "simple text : {0}, and date : {1}";
var replacedString = string.Format(template, "John",DateTime.Now);
```

string format is index based if i use your "simple text : {1}, and date : {3}" you can use this as the following

```
var template = "simple text : {1}, and date : {3}";
var replacedString = string.Format(template,"index 0", "John","index 2",DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: The problem is : i don't know what to put in, because i get that from data base
When i have "{7}" i need to put i.e : Element.toString(), when i have {10} i need to put "Template.toString()".
I want to "Template.toString() to be treated like a method or value from object proeprty.