# What can I use to get name string templating that goes beyond String.Format?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm working at task that requires a good deal of string manipulation such as:

```
string result = 
    String.Format("template text {0}, {1}, ... {150}", arg1, arg2, ... ,arg150);
```

On account of the large number of arguments, this doesn't feel elegant and I'm worried about mistakes in argument order.

ASP.NET style templates (i.e. `template text <%= arg1 %>,  <%= arg2 %>`,  would be nice, but I don't want to have to do a web request to a web server just to get at a better templating engine.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are your args on an array and you just want to concat them separated with ',' with a "template text" at the start?

Comment: How about StringBuilder or List<string> ?

Comment: Here is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733378/whats-a-good-way-of-doing-string-templating-in-net.  More suggestions can be found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620265/can-i-set-up-html-email-templates-with-asp-net

Comment: The end result will be a giant SQL script, with updates, stored proc executions, etc, so it won't only involve something that could be solved with String.Join(). Why I'm not using ADO.NET is a long story and peripheral to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine), based on Razor.

```
  string template = 
  @"<html>
      <head>
        <title>Hello @Model.Name</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        Email: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
      </body>
    </html>";

  var model = new PageModel { Name = "World", Email = "someone@somewhere.com" };
  string result = Razor.Parse(template, model);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Modern C# 6 and Newer Applications**

With the advent of C# and [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) the original answers on this question have become outdated. String Interpolation is essentially syntactic sure to make `string.Format`. It allows you to place C# and variables inside of a string. The syntax to trigger string interpolation is to put a `$` before your string quote and then anything within the curly braces will be interpolated.  The following is an example that will insert a variable `myName` into a string.

```
string myName= "Scott";
string text = $"Hello {myName}!";
```

This is all built into C# 6 and newer applications with no separate download or library/package required.

**Old/Outdated Answer**

You could use a 3rd party templating framework.  My favorite at the moment is [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) due to it's simplicity and implementations in almost every language.  The .NET library for it is [Nustache](https://github.com/jdiamond/Nustache).

The syntax for the templates is like the following:

```
This is my template I will insert a {{mustache}} right there.
```

Here's a code example for .NET.

```
using Nustache.Core;

string template = "This is my template I will insert a {{mustache}} right there.";
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string,string>();
data["mustache"] = "Beard";
string final = Render.StringToString(template, data));
```

Comment: If I could accept two answers, I would also accept this one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you can use text templates you may put your string in a `StringBuilder` and then replace all occurrences of a pattern with the proper value.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you look on the string provided by you:

```
"template text {0}, {1}, ... {150}"
```

and another

```
template text <%= arg1 %>, <%= arg2 %>
```

apart of symbolism (particular for every technology) they looks similiar. So I would say, your solution is already a good one, imo.

Or you can use "given names" in the string, like for example we do with a `@parameter` in `SQL` string. So in *parameter* itself you will have some notion about the argument.