# How to send email with different salutation in templatewith smtpclient

Tags: c#

I have written an email service class to sendout email to multiple email ids. Which sends email to multiple email ids using smtpclient class.Here is the method which sends the emails.

```
private async Task SendEmail(EmailOptions emailOptions) 
{ 
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage 
                           { 
                               Subject = emailOptions.Subject, 
                               Body = emailOptions.Body, 
                               From = new MailAddress(_mailSettings.SenderAddress, _mailSettings.SenderDisplayName), 
                               IsBodyHtml = _mailSettings.IsBodyHTML 
                           };

    foreach (var toEmail in emailOptions.ToEmails)
    {
        mail.To.Add(toEmail);
    }

    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(_mailSettings.UserName, _mailSettings.Password);

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = _mailSettings.Host,
            Port = _mailSettings.Port,
            EnableSsl = _mailSettings.EnableSSL,
            UseDefaultCredentials = _mailSettings.UseDefaultCredentials,
            Credentials = networkCredential
        };
       
    mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default;

    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail);
    smtpClient.Dispose();
}

private string GetEmailBody(string templateName) 
{
    const string templatePath = @"EmailTemplates/{0}.html";

    var body = File.ReadAllText(string.Format(templatePath, templateName));
    return body;
}
```

And this is the update place holder in email template method

```
private string UpdatePlaceHolders(string text, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyValuePairs)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && keyValuePairs != null)
        {
            foreach (var placeholder in keyValuePairs)
            {
                if (text.Contains(placeholder.Key))
                {
                    text = text.Replace(placeholder.Key, placeholder.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        return text;
}

public class EmailOption
{
        public string ToEmail { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
         public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> PlaceHolders { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the emailbody method, where I am filling the template with the username from the placeholder. For each email i send the content will be same except the salutation. Hi Mr X, Hi Mr Y. I can send mails to multiple email ids but how do i change/ specify different only the salutation in the email. In my template, I have placed a placeholder

```
Dear <username>
```

like Dear Myusername

Comment: try liquid email templates. https://auth0.com/docs/customize/email/email-templates/use-liquid-syntax-in-email-templates

Comment: Here my issue is if i am sending mail to UserName1@gmail.com the mail body should have a salutaion "Dear  UserName1" (actual username not extracted from emailid) and  ,UserName22@gmail.com the mail body should have a salutaion "Dear  UserName22" ..

Comment: I have the class above EmailOption

Comment: again, you can have a list/dictionalry of email,user name and apply each email to template to match name to replace. in this case eavry email to user#@xxx.com will have dear user# ...

Comment: so, add a logic, when placeholder name == "userName" (or something) add "Dear " in front of value. kind of "Dear " + placeholder.Value

Comment: Try using : https://www.nuget.org/packages/FormatWith
Here's an example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733378/whats-a-good-way-of-doing-string-templating-in-net/61905250#61905250

Comment: @PowerMouse You meant to loop through all the items and send mail to users one by one instead of sending a mail to multiple toemails in one go .ie foreach (var toEmail in emailOptions.ToEmails) { mail.To.Add(toEmail); } this need to be excluded and call await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail); i

Comment: each email contain unique email body related to that email object. yes. you need to send  each email separately for each dear user.