# UserControl within txt file

Tags: templates, user-controls

I working on a small page content manager.  I would like to create some variables like @contact@ that an user can add within some pages.
the @contact@ is a userControl (a contact form). 
All the pages are stored as txt files.

My question is :
Is it possible to "translate" the @contact@ variable into the userControl when I "display" the txt file ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NVelocity](http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/). It's an open source template engine that does what you want to do. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620265/can-i-set-up-html-email-templates-in-c-on-asp-net/620315#620315) as an example.

Comment: You probably want a link to the Castle fork- http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/index.html