# setting mail header in c#

Tags: c#, email

hi i need to set header content type in c#.
when i send mail from c#, i'm getting the mail with html tags. how can set content type in mail sending code?

Comment: How are you sending the mail? Show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that you asking *how can I send email in c#*:

> ```
> MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
> mail.To = "me@mycompany.com";
> mail.From = "you@yourcompany.com";
> mail.Subject = "this is a test email."; 
> mail.Body = "this is my test email body"; 
> mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
> SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";  //your real server goes here 
> SmtpMail.Send( mail );
> ```

Source: [here](http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/2.1.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    // need to set this property
    mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
```

For more alterations, you can do with templates in your email, see

- [**Can I set up HTML/Email Templates in
  C# on ASP.NET?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620265/can-i-set-up-html-email-templates-in-c-on-asp-net)

Hope this helps