# Using html page as mail body in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email, mailmessage

I have an email template in a file called template.html, how can i use it as mail body in asp.net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I set up HTML/Email Templates with ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620265/can-i-set-up-html-email-templates-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mailtemplates.aspx) with code.

Or you could use the [MailDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx) class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
File.ReadAllText("template.html")

//This is to read template.html then you can pass this through
//formatemail() function if you have or
//message.body = File.ReadAllText("template.html");
```