# Using Razor without MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to merge templates with data to create unique strings at runtime. It was suggested that I look at the [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) templating view engine that comes in ASP.NET MVC 3. Looks great, but I need to use it outside of MVC view creation.

I know I can use the core Razor engine directly, but I've also found a couple of projects that make using Razor directly easier. Like:

1. Rick Strahl's Razor Hosting Template
   Engine-
   http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/864461.aspx
2. Razor Engine on GitHub - https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

Does anyone have any guidance on using Razor outside of MVC as a standalone template engine? Any experience with these wrapper projects? are there other Razor hosting implementations I should look into?

Answer (score 7):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/29/razor-view-engine-without-mvc-at-all/) which illustrates how you could use the Razor view engine to render a template to a string.

Answer (score 6):

Look at [RazorTemplates](http://nuget.org/packages/RazorTemplates) library. It's more lightweight than RazorEngine library, it's thread-safe and has very nice minimal interface.

Comment: I thought I'd check this out. It's so simple to use! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to generate real content from razor template, you can use [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine).

Comment: that link was in the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Phil Haack [posted about this way to do it](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/01/text-templating-using-razor-the-easy-way.aspx) using a generated class.

- You create a .cshtml file and then use a compile time extension on the file to generate a class. Then you can just do this:

  ```
  var template = new RazorTemplate {
      Model = new[] { 
          new {Name = "Scott", Id = 1},
          new {Name = "Steve", Id = 2},
          new {Name = "Phil", Id = 3},
          new {Name = "David", Id = 4}
      }
  };
  Console.WriteLine(template.TransformText());
  ```

Comment: Simple takes the day in my book. Thanks for dropping this @Simon_Weaver!  You seem like a guy who might just hang out with @JonSkeet you have so much SO cred! :-)  It pays to dig through all the answers. :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice post how to use RazorEngine:
[How to create a localizable text template engine using RazorEngine](http://netmvc.blogspot.com/2012/04/localizable-text-template-engine-using.html)

Answer (score 3):

Found a really nice library by Jaap Lamfers:

[Razor 2.0 template engine, supporting layouts (on CodeProject)](http://web1.codeproject.com/Articles/423141/Razor-2-0-template-engine-supporting-layouts)

[RazorMachine (on GitHub)](https://github.com/jlamfers/RazorMachine)

Qualities:

- support _ViewStart
- support Layout
- extensible (supports something like MVC ViewEngines)
- contains samples
- lots of unit tests
- it is well documented (see CodeProject link)