# How to use razor outside of a MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I would like to know how I can use razor outside of MVC project. I have a work project which was converted from ASP pages to ASP.NET with aspx and ascx pages. Is it possible to use razor within my project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Razor without MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808348/using-razor-without-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. For a sample you can install WebMatrix http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/ and create the Bakery project using the templates.