# webapi render model as html within the controller

Tags: razor, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi controller action which creates an html email. currently i'm using string.format to create the html, as it's the simplest possible thing. I know this will become more complex moving forward and would like to use razor templating.

I have seen examples of how to do this for MVC controllers, but I cannot find any for how to do this within a `WebApiController`. Is this possible? If so do you know of any resources? My google-fu is failing me.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808348/using-razor-without-mvc  The answer given by Darin Dimitrov could well be your best bet.

Comment: thanx @MarkJones that pointed me in the right direction. in the end I went with [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/). It was just a bit cleaner to implement.

Answer (score 7):

Checkout this article [Rendering an ASP.NET MVC View to a string in a Web Api Controller](http://wouterdekort.blogspot.ro/2012/10/rendering-aspnet-mvc-view-to-string-in.html) by  Wouter de Kort

```
 public static string RenderViewToString(string controllerName, string viewName, 
                                         object viewData)
{
    HttpContextBase contextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(contextBase, routeData, 
                                                   new EmptyController());

    var razorViewEngine = new RazorViewEngine();
    var razorViewResult = razorViewEngine.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, 
                                                     "", false);

    var writer = new StringWriter();
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, razorViewResult.View, 
           new ViewDataDictionary(viewData), new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
    razorViewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);

    return writer.ToString();
}

private class EmptyController : ControllerBase
{
    protected override void ExecuteCore() { }
}

//You can simply call this from anywhere in your Web Api Controller: 

RenderViewToString("controller", "view", model)
```

Comment: what controller name should be sent if the view is a shared view?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this ViewRenderer class with great success:

https://github.com/RickStrahl/WestwindToolkit/blob/master/Westwind.Web.Mvc/Utils/ViewRenderer.cs

Call it like this:

```
var html = ViewRenderer.RenderView("~/views/emails/ActivationEmail.cshtml", emailModel);
```

Comment: Any way to get this to work within ASP.NET Core 2.2?