# Helper class for creating HTML emails in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, html

I was using the default `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` classes for creating and sending HTML emails from a web forms website. The problem is I have a lot of hard coded HTML for formatting the email that gets sent. Is there a class that helps format emails for .NET? Any resources or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620265/can-i-set-up-html-email-templates-with-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the MailDefinition class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx

> The MailDefinition class can be used
>   by controls to create a MailMessage
>   object from a text file or a string
>   that contains the body of the e-mail
>   message. Use the MailDefinition class
>   to simplify creating predefined e-mail
>   messages to be sent by a control. If
>   you want to send e-mail not using a
>   control, see the System.Net.Mail
>   class.
>
> You can make text substitutions in the
>   body of the e-mail message by passing
>   to the CreateMailMessage method an
>   IDictionary instance that maps strings
>   to their replacements.
>
> The MailMessage object created by the
>   MailDefinition class is sent using the
>   Send method of the SmtpClient class.
>   To be able to send e-mail, you must
>   configure an SMTP mail server in your
>   Web.config file. For more information,
>   see the  Element (Network
>   Settings).

Answer (score 1):

You could create your email templates as razor views. Check out [this blog post](http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/use-razor-for-email-template-outside-asp-dot-net-mvc).