# Using LoadControl on pages with server controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a user control template that I can send as email.

In a utility class I have a method that contains this code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Page p = new Page();
UserControl ctrl = (UserControl)p.LoadControl("~/EmailTemplates/OrderConfirmation.ascx");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
Html32TextWriter htw = new Html32TextWriter(sw);

ctrl.RenderControl(htw);
```

This correctly writes the user controls text, but if I want to use a server control such as a listview inside of the controls page, the listview is never evaluated. It seems that only inline code blocks are evaluated. How can I get around this?

Comment: Can you paste some code showing us what the control looks like? Because it should work fine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should actually add the control to a page and execute the page:

```
    var page = new FormlessPage();
    var ctrl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl("~/EmailTemplates/OrderConfirmation.ascx");

    page.Controls.Add(ctl);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
    return writer.ToString();
```

Formless page simply looks like:

```
public class FormlessPage : Page
{
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
    }
}
```

It allows your control to have input elements without a `<form>` wrapper.

This method will call your page lifecycle methods and bind up your form elements nicely.

Comment: Thank you...So much. This has been a frustrating day. That's very interesting that you can execute the page like that.

Comment: @Nick: You're welcome. I'm doing something similar, where I re-use user controls to build HTML reports by switching the user controls to a "read-only" mode. I remember spending hours trying to build or  track down a solution. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Public function (aka ProcessLoad), instead of Page_Load function and call it immediately after loading the control. This way you can pass parameters to your UserControl as well.