# How to bind HTML fields with javascript object

Tags: javascript, html

I have to bind HTML fields with javascript objects.
This is my HTML-

```
<div>
   <img src="value1"><br/>    
   <p>value2</p>
   <a href="value3"/>
</div>
```

I have `value1`,`value2`,`value3` in javascript function. How can I bind this values to html fields?

Comment: What do you mean to say by `javascript Oject`. Please clarify

Comment: I think he mean Javascript objects var a= {}; ?

Comment: By javascript object, I just meant javascript variables. `var value1`

Comment: so you mean when you change value1, you want the img src=value1 to be updated automatically too ?

Comment: @cherhan- yes exactly. These values are in a aspx page, every time it loads, values might be different.

Comment: So you mean http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860

Comment: Or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620265/can-i-set-up-html-email-templates-with-asp-net

Comment: @mplungjan- My requirement is like values are there in a aspx.cs page and i need to bind those values inside fields of a div and again same values needed to binded in another javascript function. So which would be fine- calling values from code behind to div and javascript function or save code behind values to var variable to a javascript function and both div and javascript function takes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**FIDDLE here**](http://jsfiddle.net/epUjw/)

If you have values in javascript that you want to change in the HTML the best is to create those elements in javascript. But if I just follow your HTML you can use:
(there are some markup errors in your html, so I changed that)

html

```
<div><img id="value1" src="#" /><br/>    
<p id="value2">value2</p>
<a id="value3" href="#">Link</a></div>
```

script

```
// here you give value to the js variables
var value1 = 'image.jpg'; 
var value2 = 'Test text';
var value3 = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
// here you put/bind the values with the ids in the html
document.getElementById('value1').src = value1;
document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = value2;
document.getElementById('value3').href= value3
```

Comment: I think he wants to databind them

Comment: I followed your code- end up in an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null `

Comment: @Sandy, that means `document.getElementById('value1')` doesn't exist. Please double check the id, in the javascript and your html. Are you running the code inside a function? Did you see my FIDDLE, does it work as you expect there?

Comment: @sergio- this is what I tried- `<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sTitle = '';
var sLinkBack = '';
window.onload = load();
function load() {
    sTitle = 'Test';
    sLinkBack = 'http://www.google.com';
    document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = sTitle;
    document.getElementById('value3').href = sLinkBack;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <div>
   <p id="value2">value2</p>
   <a id="value3" href="#">Link</a>
  </div> 
</body>` whats wrong here?

Comment: @Sandy, it looks good, check here (http://jsfiddle.net/yxgKW/) you could try to put the script part inside the body though.

Comment: @Sandy, try `window.onload = load;` without the `()`. By using the `()` the function runs imediatly without waiting for the window.onload

Comment: @Sandy, nice! glad I could help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32936/discussion-between-sandy-and-sergio)

Answer (score -1):

For example:

```
<div><img id="image" src=value1><br/>    
<p id="paragraph">value2</p>
<a id="link" href=value3/></div>

document.getElementById('image').src = value1;
document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHtml = value2;
document.getElementById('link').href=value3
```

Answer (score -1):

bind like that document.getElementById('image').src = value1;