# Accessing child controls that are in a templated user control ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, user-controls

The following codes are simplified.

The user-control ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BaseFormControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="SOPR.CustomForms.BaseFormControl" %>
<fieldset class="fset1">
</fieldset>
```

This is my user control code-behind:

```
public partial class BaseFormControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {



        [TemplateContainer(typeof(ContentContainer))]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public ITemplate Content { get; set; }



   void Page_Init()
        {




            if (Content != null)
            {
                ContentContainer cc = new ContentContainer();
                Content.InstantiateIn(cc);
                contentHolder.Controls.Add(cc);
            }
        }
```

My usage in the view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddOperator.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="SOPR.Cadastro.AddOperator" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" ID="maincont" runat="server"     EnableViewState="true">
    <uc:BaseFormControl ID="BaseFormControl1" runat="server">
        <Content>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="keytbcss" MaxLength="4" ID="keytb"
                NewLine="false" />
        </Content>
    </uc:BaseFormControl>
```

I'm trying to access the "keytb" control on the code-behind, but its like it didnt exist (like using a variable that doesn't exist). Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION --------------------------
I found a quite nice solution, just add [TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)] to the ITemplate property of the user control and everything gets seen. I can now use just like it was a normal page control.

```
public partial class BaseFormControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{



[TemplateContainer(typeof(ContentContainer))]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
public ITemplate Content { get; set; }
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find a control in a webform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619449/find-a-control-in-a-webform)

Comment: Interesting, I did'nt knew of `TemplateInstance`. +1 for your solution ;)

Comment: If you add your solution as an answer, then I will upvote it.

Comment: Thanks, i will add it once i'm able. Glad to be helpful. For the sake of completeness, i found the answer here: http://geekswithblogs.net/CodeSpeaker/archive/2009/07/04/templated-user-controls-in-asp.net-for-better-maintainability.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLUTION --------------------------
I found a quite nice solution, just add [TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)] to the ITemplate property of the user control and everything gets seen. I can now use just like it was a normal page control.

```
public partial class BaseFormControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{



[TemplateContainer(typeof(ContentContainer))]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
public ITemplate Content { get; set; }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a method to acces content controls in your user control :

```
public Control FindInnerControl  (string id)
{
  if (contentHolder.Controls.Count > 0)
  {
    return contentHolder.Controls [0].FindControl (id); //The first control is your ContentContainer
  }
  return null;
}
```

then in the code behind of your page you can do

```
TextBox txtKeytbcss = (TextBox) BaseFormControl1.FindInnerControl ("keytbcss");
```

Comment: That's not working, always returns null. I found a  quite nice solution, just add [TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)] to the ITemplate property of the user control and everything gets seen.

Comment: You're right, cause you add your control to `ContentContainer cc`, and then cc to `contentHolder`. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a control inside a template, you are giving it a sample of how the content is going to be. Imagine that you are giving a content of a grid in a template with some id "SomeTextBox", SomeTextBox can't occur multiple times as the rows in the grid increase. The control will name it dynamically during the run time.

But still you have a way, you have to find the container control and apply,
Control.FindControl()  method on it. FindControl() takes your template control's ID, which you have given in the design time.