# Getting text box values through loop

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, textbox

I've 10 text boxes txt_Address1, txt_Address2...txt_Address10 and 10 columns to store their values in database i.e. Address1, Address2...Address10. Now I want to get each value of text box and store it into its corresponding column. For this rather than writing 10 lines of code for each text box, I want to do it by FOR loop. Can anybody suggest me the suitable solution?

Comment: you can create an array and add all the txt_Ad... to it.  TextBox[] textBoxes = new TextBox[] { txt_Addr1, txt_Addr2,...}. And loop over that.

Comment: see my answer, you can add all your textbox into a list or added it into an array and loop it, the TextBox is a reference type which means that declaring a TextBox a = txt_address10 does not make a copy of it, instead it creates a pointer to txt_address10

Comment: Make sure you really want to do this.  People are telling you how, but it looks like a bad database design and a consequent waste of time.  See my answer below.

Comment: @user1646737 But this is how my client wants me to do.

Comment: Sometimes, you have to follow orders, but I'd explain the problem to the client and tell him how a modest change can make his end product infinitely more versatile.  If he declines, then, you can write all the poor code for a poorly-designed database.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the textboxes, store them in a collection

```
List<TextBox> textboxControls = new List<TextBox>();
```

Then when you create them, add them to the collection

```
textboxControls.Add(control);
```

Then you can loop over them and access their values

```
foreach(var control in textboxControls )
    DoSomethingWithText(control.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the textbox in an array of TextBox;

```
TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
TextBox txt2 = new TextBox();
TextBox txt3 = new TextBox();
TextBox txtN = new TextBox();

TextBox[] allTextBoxes = new TextBox[] { txt1, txt2, txt3, txtN };

foreach(TextBox item in allTextBoxes)
{
StoreValue(item.Text);
}
```

OR you can use

```
List<TextBox> lst = new List<TextBox>();
lst.Add(txt1);
lst.Add(txt2);
lst.Add(txt3);

foreach(TextBox item in lst)
{
    StoreValue(item.Text);
}
```

Comment: But in this case also I need to declare 10 text boxes for each of my text box. Can it be done by FOR loop in place of foreach loop?

Comment: sure you can create textbox dynamically and place it in the form like this :

Comment: List<TextBox> lst = new List<TextBox>(); for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { TextBox txt = new TextBox(); lst.Add(txt); form1.Controls.Add(txt); txt.Top = (i + 1) * 20; DoSomething(txt.Text); }

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in a list, and iterate over that list ...

**Edit:** Seems lostincomputer answered twenty seconds ahead of me ... 
same same ... both will work

Answer (score 0):

Or you can access them from the form without the list:

```
foreach(Control control in MyForm.Controls)
{
    if(control is TextBox)
    {
       //do what you want

    }
}
```

Or if you have them in a groupBox

```
foreach(Control control in myGroupBox.Controls)
{
     if(control is TextBox)
     {
         //do what you want
     }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Or with the FOR loop:

```
//Controls is the Controls collection of the form
for(int i=0;i<Controls.Count;i++)
        {
            if(Controls[i] is TextBox)
            {
                //do what you want
            }
        }
```

Comment: You will also need to cast the `control` as a `TextBox` in this case. Perhaps it will be better to cast is first `control as Textbox` and do a null check. This way you only cast once.

Answer (score 0):

Before you spend (waste) time writing code to work for a database designed like that, you should re-design your database.  It is not a good idea to have 10 columns in a table for 10 addresses.   You should be able to have anywhere from 0 - infinity addresses.   Look up how to make a relational database.

Basically:

**Table:  Customer**

```
CustomerID
Name
Etc.
```

**Table: CustomerAddresses**

```
CustomerID
Address
City
State
Zip
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1 :**
you can go through the all `Form` controls and only consider the  `TextBox` controls.

**Step 2:** from all Form `TextBox` Controls filter the TextBox's that contain `Name` as "`txt_Address%`" here `%` canbe anything like 1,2,3,4...etc.,

**Code is as below:**

```
        List<String> txtValues=new List<string>();
        foreach (var control in this.Controls)
        {
         if((control is TextBox) && (((TextBox) control).Name.Contains("txt_Address")))
             txtValues.Add(((TextBox) control).Text.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Controls.Find() like this:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find("txt_Address" + i.ToString(), true);
            if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)matches[0];
                // ... do something with "tb" ...
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do I need to add some namespace for Controls.Find()? If yes, then Kindly tell me. Because I'm not able to find Find method in intellicense.

Comment: You didn't specify...WinForms?, WebForms?, WPF?, something else?

Comment: I'm talking about WebForms.

Comment: I'm not a web developer, sorry.  See andleer's answer over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/619628/2330053).

Answer (score 0):

```
var columns = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) columns.Add("Address" + i, string.Empty);

var textBoxes = Controls.Find("txt_Address", true).Where(t => t is TextBox).ToList();

columns.ToList().ForEach(c =>
{
    var index = c.Key.Replace("Address", string.Empty);
    var textBox = textBoxes.FirstOrDefault(t => index.Equals(t.Name.Replace("txt_Address", string.Empty)));
    if (textBox != null) columns[c.Key] = textBox.Text;
});
```