# To get values from db and assign button text

Tags: c#

I have a deptarment table and have 5 rows. I have a select command which gets dept_name column alone from the department table. I want to assign these values (row["Dept_Name"].tostring()) to each button one by one.
ex: if my output is 
dept1
dept2
dept3
dept4
dept5

I want to assign text value of buttons (5 buttons already in design) as button1.text = "dept1";
button2.text = "dept2";
button3.text = "dept3"; and so on.

How do i achieve it.
I used the following code.

```
           MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myconnectionstring);
        string getdept = "SELECT DEPT_NAME FROM DEPTARTMENT";
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getdept,con);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow Row in dt.Rows)
        {

            Button1.Text = Row["DEPT_NAME"].ToString();
       /* i am stuck at this part on how to each row to a separte button text.*/

        }
```

Comment: Don't do database access before you learn the language fundamentals... Seriously, just don't.

Comment: @grant , if i dont use foreach statement , then how do i specify row increment and set it to different button text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `for`-loop and [`Controls.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string buttonName = "Button" + i.ToString();
    Control[] buttons = this.Controls.Find(buttonName, false);
    if(buttons.Length == 1 && buttons[0] is Button)
    {
        Button btn = (Button) buttons[0];
        btn.Text = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>("DEPT_NAME");
    }
    else throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
}
```

Comment: It worked as well @tim. But this was the exact functionality i was looking for.. :) thank you. But it worked when i changed this.controld.find(buttonname,true); instead of false.

Comment: @Ameena: i haven't used the recursive version with reason. It can be problematic, you could find controls which are not the control you are looking for.  Instead you should use the right parent control in the first place. If it's for example in a groupbox or panel you should use `panel.Controls.Find(buttonName, false);`.

Answer (score 2):

no need to iterate:

```
Button1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["DEPT_NAME"].ToString();
Button2.Text = dt.Rows[1]["DEPT_NAME"].ToString();
Button3.Text = dt.Rows[2]["DEPT_NAME"].ToString();
Button4.Text = dt.Rows[3]["DEPT_NAME"].ToString();
Button5.Text = dt.Rows[4]["DEPT_NAME"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @fubo. I over thinked the concept and got stuck. thanks for guiding. :)

Answer (score 0):

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619449/find-a-control-in-a-webform), you can do

```
var i = 0;
foreach (DataRow Row in dt.Rows)
{
    i++;
    var button = Page.GetControl("Button" + i) as Button;
    button.Text = Row["DEPT_NAME"].ToString();
}
```