# Panel Control and Check panel property is Empty

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I want to Check that whether a panel have some form or not.
kindly tell me the best condition.
if panel have some form inside it than bool variable should be true.
the code that i have write is below.Kindly answer this question as soon as possible. thanks.

this is a button click event.
i want to check that when i click on a button its first check these conditions.
1. check if form have existing this form that i want to pass in it than break 
   it and make bool variable true.
2. if it does't have than clear all form inside the panel and generate click event form inside it.

```
enter code here

    private void btn_dashboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isOpen = false;
        dash = new Dashboard();
        if (panel_window_data.Controls.Equals(dash))
        {
            isOpen = true;
        }
        if (isOpen == false)
        {
            panel_window_data.Controls.Clear();
            dash.TopLevel = false;
            panel_window_data.Controls.Add(dash);
            dash.Height = panel_window_data.Height;
            dash.Width = panel_window_data.Width;
            dash.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cant see your code, so cant help you. Please consider giving us an example

Comment: when i write code here it give me error

Comment: Just copy/paste your code then click the {} button to format the code and then touch it up to make it readable.

Comment: Your code has more problems, but the most significant is, that it will always execute the `if (isOpen == false)` condition. Why? Because you always create a new `dash = new Dashboard();`. Therefore the newly created control can not be a part of existing control. The second problem is, you use `panel_window_data.Controls.Equals(dash)`. And a list of components can never be equal to a single component.

Comment: kindly #Julo give me the solution for it please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/619628/7907133 Maybe this can help you, it makes use of several extension methods to flatten the hierarchy and then search for the control according to the ID assigned to your control. But you can use it with other parameters as well, like 'typeof'

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code in every single btn, and actually works.

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        // to show other form inside panel in main form
        users objuser = new users();
        pnlobjform.Controls.Clear();
        objuser.TopLevel = false;
        pnlobjform.Controls.Add(objuser);
        objuser.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        objuser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        objuser.Show();
        /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
```